# Codeigniter-POST not working via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form, whose values I am trying to post after serializing to a controller via ajax. Below is the form:
**Form**

```
<form method="post" id="frm_reg_student" class="stop-propagation registration-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="register[user_type]" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="register[status_id]" value="1">
  <div class="stud_register_error"></div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input" class="control-label font-12 font-blue">First Name <span>*</span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name" name="register[first_name]">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input" class="control-label font-12 font-blue">Last Name  <span class="req">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Your Last Name" name="register[last_name]">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div> 
</form>
```

**js**

```
$(".js-btn_reg_student").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var serialData= $( "#frm_reg_student" ).serialize();
        alert(serialData);
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/register/signup/',
            data: serialData,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
                output = JSON.parse(result);
                if(result) {
                    if( 'success' == output.type ) {
                        location.href = output.location;
                    } else {
                        $('.stud_register_error').html(output.message);    
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller**

```
public function signup(){
      if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
      print_r($_POST);
  }
}
```

Here, `$_POST` comes out to be empty, it never goes inside the loop. If you see in the JS, I have included an alert with the serialized data, which even shows me the proper serialized data. I believe it is something wrong with the way I am posting it.
Any help!

Comment: have you tried removing the $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] verification?

Comment: @Yohanan yes I have tried that. Still it returns empty. Something like "Array ()"

Comment: Please try using $this->input->post('register')

Comment: Tried that too. Still empty

Comment: Before you focus on your XHR version: try using a regular post method on your form to the URL mentioned in your JS. Do you see your POST variables as expected?

Comment: Well I get the array. Used the same code which you have used.

Comment: @VivekShah do you have anything else in mind as to why it would not be giving me results? If it works for you with the exact same code, then probably a machine-specific issue?

Comment: You can debug. Try to echo something else directly rather then post value. Like just echo 'test'; inside the signup function and check its url 127.0.0.1/{directory_name}/index.php/register/signup. If it shows that echo value then there is some issue with your post code which I thing is not

Answer (score 0):

Try on ajax

```
$(".js-btn_reg_student").click(function(e){

    var formdata = $( "#frm_reg_student" ).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('register/signup');?>",
        data: formdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
        if (json[success]) {
            alert(json['post']);
        } else {

        }

        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And controller

```
public function signup() {

    $data = array(
        'success' => false,
        'post' => ''
    );

    if ($this->input->server("REQUEST_METHOD") == 'POST')
    {

        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['post'] = $_POST;

    }

    echo json_encode($data);

 }
```

Comment: Nope, it did not go inside the loop. {'success':false, 'post':''}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $('#js-btn_reg_student').click(function () {
      $.ajax ({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/test/signup/',
        data: $('#frm_reg_student').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
          if(result.status == 'success')
          {
            alert(result.name);
          }
          else
          {
            alert(result.status);
          }
        }
      });
   });
```

And in Controller

```
public function signup ()
{
   if($this->input->post())
   {
    $data = array('status' => 'success');
    $data['name'] = $this->input->post('register[first_name]');
   }
   else
   {
    $data = array('status' => 'failed');
   }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Try it and let me know if it works or not  :)

Comment: Did not work out. This is the output: {"status":"failed"}

Comment: Just now I updated.Try once again with my updated code.

Comment: same output again

Comment: Check the form id,button id in my code.Change it to your appropriate ids and it will work bro.I tested with your above form.

Comment: also don't forget to change the ajax url in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code.

```
$(".js-btn_reg_student").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var serialData= $( "#frm_reg_student" ).serialize();
        alert(serialData);
        $.ajax ({
            url: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/register/signup/',
            method : 'POST', 
            data: serialData,
            success: function(result) {                                
                if(result) {
                    if( 'success' == output.type ) {
                        location.href = output.location;
                    } else {
                        $('.stud_register_error').html(output.message);    
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all the answers were correct in their own way. I figured out that it might be possible that it is not getting the DOM upon submit so I simply put it in document.ready and it worked!

Thanks